# How to override a Dart method on instantiation?

Tags: flutter, dart

In Java, one can do something like this:

```
class Example {
    void methodA(int x) {}
}
```

And then:

```
Example obj = new Example() {
    @Override
    void methodA(int x) {
        //some implementation here
    }
}
```

Is there any way to override a method on object instantiation in Dart?